# Find a two-term asymptotic expansion of $xe^{-x} = \epsilon$.

Tags: asymptotics

I want to find a two-term asymptotic expansion of the equation above. For the small root, I know the first term may be $\epsilon$, but I don't know how to find the second term. Moreover, I don't know how to find the root tending to infinite either.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Do you mean  that you want the expansion of $x$ as a function of $\epsilon$ ?  If this is the case, look at *Lambert function*

Comment: See the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem). The article has the Lambert $W$ function as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I was taught to do asymptotics the heuristic way, so please forgive the handwaviness below. There are more sophisticated ways to do things if you want more than two terms.)

### Small root

We have seen that the first term is $x \sim \epsilon$. For the next term, suppose that
$$ x \sim \epsilon + a \epsilon^n $$
where $n > 1$.

Noting that $x \mathrm{e}^{-x} \sim x (1 - x)$, we have

\begin{align}
  (\epsilon + a \epsilon^n) (1 - \epsilon - a \epsilon^n) &\sim \epsilon \\
  \epsilon - \epsilon^2 + a \epsilon^n &\sim \epsilon,
\end{align}

where we have discarded terms smaller than $\epsilon^n$. We see that $n = 2$ (which is indeed greater than $1$) and $a = 1$. Hence, to two terms,

$$
  x \sim \epsilon + \epsilon^2.
$$

### Large root

The large root is not as straightforward. Taking logarithms we have
$$
  \log x - x = \log\epsilon.
$$

Now, if $x$ is exceedingly large, then we may discard $\log x \ll x$, giving the very crude estimate
$$
  x \sim \log\frac{1}{\epsilon}.
$$

For the next term, suppose that
$$
  x \sim \log\frac{1}{\epsilon} + x_1
$$
where $x_1 \ll \log(1/\epsilon)$. Substituting into the log expression, we get

\begin{align}
  \log \left( \log\frac{1}{\epsilon} + x_1 \right) - \log\frac{1}{\epsilon} - x_1 &\sim \log\epsilon \\
  x_1 &\sim \log \left( \log\frac{1}{\epsilon} + x_1 \right) \\
      &\sim \log \left( \log\frac{1}{\epsilon} \right),
\end{align}
which, for exceedingly exceedingly small $\epsilon$, is indeed much less than $\log(1/\epsilon)$.

Hence to two terms,
$$
  x \sim \log\frac{1}{\epsilon} + \log \log\frac{1}{\epsilon}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I just start to learn this subject and it helps me a lot.